# EditField Not Receiving Input From "0" Key

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I have two EditFeilds that need numeric input.  The issue is that that zero does not seem to work in any simulator simulating a handset with a hardware keyboard.

Both EditFields are initialized with:

`private EditField editField = new EditField( EditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC );`

I am I right in assuming that the BB OS should be taking care of the input type.  The EditFields need the ability to enter decimal points (but not math operators).  I know that the key press on the 0 key is getting caught, since I can print out the key code to the console (but that only works when debugging).

Could this be just a simulator issue?

Comment: Why don't you use private EditField editField = new EditField( EditField.FILTER_NUMERIC ); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike, I can not reproduce your issue on a range of simulators. What simulator do you use? Do you subclass from `EditField` or use the `EditField` class directly?

Comment: It happens using the Tour and Bold simulators.  I'm pretty sure it's a simulator issue since this doesn't happen on Torch or Storm simulators.  I'm using the EditField directly and targeting version 5.0.

Comment: @Mike D: The app I'm working on uses `EditField.FILTER_NUMERIC` for more than a year. If any customer had this issue I'd have been definitelly notified to fix it (without this feature the app becomes just useless). Since we support Tour and Bold on OS 5.0 I think you may assume this is a simulator specific issue.